# Chrome does not render Latex at all

Tags: support, mathjax, google-chrome

I'm working on an older laptop with Windows 7. It does not render any latex equations on websites like Math Stack Exchange. I opened the source for a [page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in it.

It shows the following errors:
[image]

In Sources, I realized that it uses cdn.mathjax.org as shown, instead of cdnjs.cloudflare.com:
[image]

It also does not open script for Mathjax.js (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full), saying 'This site can't be reached'.

I assume this is the reason why the latex cannot be rendered in it. How do I correct this issue?  I haven't really worked with scripts, so if there are any additions or subtractions to be done, do let me know how to or refer me to a page which explains it. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using any adblockers or blocking 3rd party javascripts?

Comment: When I click on the link you posted, I see the text of the Javascript: `if(document.getElementById...`  I'm using Chromium Version 87.0.4280.66 on Fedora 32.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not using any adblockers or blocking 3rd party javascripts, as far as I understand. Is there a way to test it for sure?

Comment: @hardmath Yes, I believe that is the javascript that needs to be accessible. I can open it too on a newer laptop, but the laptop I mentioned cannot reach that site. The Chrome version is 87.0.4280.88 on both the laptops.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I found that an antivirus was blocking some adware. Disabling it has enabled rendering of the Latex again! Thank you!